# Reason for oil like substance in coolant reservoir and under radiator cap?

Tags: ford, coolant, ranger

I have a 96 Ford Ranger 3.0. There is an oil like substance in the coolant reservoir and under radiator cap. Oil is clean with no loss. Transmission is idling fine. No overheating of cooling system. What could the oil like substance be and how could it get there?

Comment: Would it be possible to take a picture and post it here?

Comment: Some radiator model have also an automatic transmission oil cooler embedded in the radiator. A failure(mainly rust) can occur and mix the oil and coolant.

Comment: How much do you actually drive your vehicle? Is it used only for really short trips where it doesn't get completely warmed up?

Answer (score -1):

You may have a tiny leak between the water passages and the oil passages in the engine. I would also expect to see some antifreeze in the oil and on the dipstick like mayonnaise in the oil.

Comment: Which would be caused by what? I know a head gasket would cause this but the OP and other users might not. This should probably be a comment